# `coplot` substitute in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to replicate the example, given in *Statistical Models in S*. Here is the code given in the book.

```
data(ethanol)
attach(ethanol)
E.intervals <- co.intervals(E, number = 9, overlap = 1/4)
coplot(NOx ~ C | E, given.values = E.intervals,
                    panel = function(x,y) panel.smooth(x,y,degree = 1, span = 1))
```

This code works only in `S`, because `panel.smooth` function doesn't have `degree` argument.
So I used

```
coplot(NOx ~ C | E, given.values = E.intervals,
                    panel = function(x,y,...) panel.smooth(x,y, iter = 1, span = 1))
```

I would like to use `lattice` graphics package because it has `panel.loess` function that is similar to `panel.smooth` from `S`, but I haven't found the function similar to `coplot`. I think it is `xyplot`. If it is, can you suggest me the parameter equivalent to `given.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it might be done, it is not quite the same but very close.

```
require(gridExtra)
require(lattice)
data(ethanol)
E.intervals <- equal.count(E, number = 9, overlap = 1/4)
plot1 <- plot(E.intervals)
plot2 <- xyplot(NOx ~ C | E.intervals, data = ethanol, span = 1, layout = c(3,3),
                panel = function(x,y,span){
                panel.xyplot(x, y);
                panel.loess(x, y, span);
               })
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2, nrow=2)
```

The difference is the hight of the upper plot, it should be smaller.